# Reference sibling objects inside object whose name has a - inside

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this:

```
var myVar = {
    "phantom-ee": {
        doWork: function() {

        },
        doOtherWork: function() {}
    },
    "sameAsPhantom": myVar["phantom-ee"]
}
```

However, I get a myVar is undefined.  I also tried:

```
var myVar = {
    "phantom-ee": {
        doWork: function() {

        },
        doOtherWork: function() {}
    },
    "sameAsPhantom": this["phantom-ee"]
}
```

This code doesn't throw an error on the definition but during execution...

How would I make sameAsPhantom refer to the same object as phantom-ee?

Comment: You can move the ```sameAsPhantom``` declaration below the ```myVar```. This should work: ```var myVar = { "phantom-ee": ... }; myVar["sameAsPhantom"] = myVar["phantom-ee"];```

Comment: You can't directly assign one property to reference another because the object hasn't been compiled at that point. You have to do it after it has been compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myVar = {
  'phantom-ee': {
    doWork: function() {

    },
    doOtherWork: function() {}
  }
};

myVar.sameAsPhantom = myVar['phantom-ee'];
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yteuqfg1/**

Comment: @code4cause this answer doesn't take it out of the object